# Derive dataframe using count of data and splitting the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[a,a,b,b,c,c], 'bar':[0,1,0,1,0,1], 'count':[110, 42, 90, 87, 165, 23]})

+-----+-----+-------+
| foo | bar | count |
+-----+-----+-------+
| a   | 0   | 110   |
+-----+-----+-------+
| a   | 1   | 42    |
+-----+-----+-------+
| b   | 0   | 90    |
+-----+-----+-------+
| b   | 1   | 87    |
+-----+-----+-------+
| c   | 0   | 165   |
+-----+-----+-------+
| c   | 1   | 23    |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

I would like to derive a new dataframe from the current which looks like the following:

```
+-----+--------+--------+
| foo | Count0 | Count1 |
+-----+--------+--------+
| a   | 110    | 42     |
+-----+--------+--------+
| b   | 90     | 87     |
+-----+--------+--------+
| c   | 165    | 23     |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

How would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) as follows:

```
df1 = df1.pivot(index='foo', columns='bar', values='count')
df1.columns = ['Count1', 'Count2']
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

The columns needs to be renamed separately but could be made automatic if the number of rows in each `bar` is a larger number.

Resulting dataframe:

```
  foo  Count1  Count2
0   a     110      42
1   b      90      87
2   c     165      23
```